# Limit with norm

Tags: limits

I would like to study :

$\lim \limits_{||(x,y)|| \rightarrow \infty} (1+|x|+|y|)\sin(y^2)$

I reasoned this way ;

$\left|f(x,y) \right|=\left| 1+\left|x \right|+|y|\sin\left(y^2 \right) \right| \leq \left| 1+|x|+|y| \right| \leq 1+|x|+|y| \rightarrow +\infty$ with the norm $ \left\|(x,y)\right\|_1=|x|+|y|$

Hence $\lim \limits_{||(x,y)|| \rightarrow \infty} (1+|x|+|y|)\sin(y^2)=\infty$

Could you tell me if the way I do it is correct ?
Thank you

Comment: Take care! When a number is smaller than another number that goes to $\infty$, it doesn't mean that the first number also. What is happening when $y^2 = 2 k \pi$, with $k \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Thanks for noticing to me that, then $\sin y^2=0$ hence the expression would tend to $0$ but how to deduce the value of the limit for all $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: The expression won't tend to $0$. It vanishes for the points $(x,2 k \pi)$, while the sequence $f(0, 2 k \pi +\frac{\pi}{2})$ tends to $\infty$. Conclusion: the limit doesn't exist.